# Minimizing MVC memory consumption footprint

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, memory-management

How can I minimize the footprint of a website built using MVC. My application currently runs at around 20mb, I'd like to reduce it if possible.

Edit: I've switched hosts, problem solved.

Comment: Stop, put down Task Manager, and walk away.

Comment: Maybe we should be asking you this question. How'd you get it down to 20MB? ;)

Comment: What method of measurement are you using to come up with "around 20mb"? It sounds ridiculously low.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

20mb is pretty good! Consider all the libraries and managed resources that need to be brought in to make pretty much any .NET application of notable size work.

If you reach a point where you can point to your application's memory footprint and say with confidence that is actually causing whatever problem you're encountering, then get some details together. Use something like [Red Gate](http://www.red-gate.com/) products to profile your application and see where the memory hogs and bottlenecks are. Trying to guess beforehand never works.

And aside from that, how much memory does your server have? 2gb? 4gb? Of course we should always pay due diligence to making sure our applications aren't hogs, but at the same time - take advantage of the breathing room modern computing has afforded us!

Comment: Thats the problem, I currently have an extremely limited server, with just about 1gb

Comment: @Alex properly configured Windows should take about 350, your database server maybe 200, misc. services another 50, that leaves 300mb for your app. If it was taking 260mb that might be a cause for concern. 20, not so much.

Answer (score 1):

20mb is not much memory at all in the grand scheme of things.  Optimize when you need to, doing so before can be wasteful.  Are you hitting resource limitations on your hardware?